# Помогите составить запросы vk android api sdk

Tags: vkontakte-api

Список или количество подписчиков пользователя (зная его id)? Список или количество друзей пользователя?

Знаю как получить своих друзей, что добавить надо?

```
VKRequest request = VKApi.friends().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "first_name", "last_name"));
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получить количество подписчиков пользователя, делаете запрос так:

```
final VKRequest request = VKApi.users().getFollowers(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.USER_ID, 66748,
            VKApiConst.COUNT, 1000));
```

В этом запросе вместо "66748" вводите нужный идентификатор пользователя. В поле "COUNT" указываем количество подписчиков, информацию о которых нужно получить.

Обрабатываем полученный ответ так:

```
try {
                JSONObject r = response.json.getJSONObject("response");
                System.out.println("Подписчиков у пользователя с id 66748: " + r.getString("count"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

В консоль у вас будет выведено:

> I/System.out: Подписчиков у пользователя с id 66748: 39261